# Reading an array from file. (java)

Tags: java, string, file, split, int

Hello it is my code to read from file

```
case 11: {
    String line;
    String temp[];
    System.out.println("Podaj nazwę pliku z jakiego odczytać playlistę.");
    nazwa11 = odczyt.next();
    try {

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(nazwa11);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        playlists.add(new Playlist(bufferedReader.readLine()));
        x++;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            String delimiter = "|";
            temp = line.split(delimiter);
            int rok;
            rok = Integer.parseInt(temp[2]);
            playlists.get(x).dodajUtwor(temp[0], temp[1], rok);


        }


        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Nie znaleziono pliku: '" + nazwa11 + "'");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + nazwa11 + "'");
    }
    break;
}
```

Example file looks like this:

```
Pop
Test|Test|2010
Test1|Test1|2001
```

Gives me error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "s"
```

Why my line.split doesn't split when it finds "|"? I guess it splits t-e-s, any tips?

Comment: Your delimiter is being evaluated as a regular expression, so you need to escape the pipe: `delimiter = "\\|";`

Answer (score 2):

The pipe character "|" is one of the meta characters that carries a special meaning while performing the match.

This [page](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html) gives you the complete lists of these special characters and their meanings.

So, in your program, modify the following line,

```
String delimiter = "|";
```

to

```
String delimiter = "\\|";
```

This will give you the result that you want.